# Shiny Screening App - User Filter / Mutate / Modify

Tags: r, shiny, dt, rhandsontable, quosure

I'm in the process of creating a Shiny screening application, which would allow users to type R commands like `filter` and `mutate` on a predetermined dataframe.

Personally, I think the most user friendly way to do this would be to have a blank dataframe column containing screening parameters, where users could input commands like `filter(mpg >= 21)` or `mutate(cyl_sq = cyl^2)` using the `mtcars` dataset as an example.

**Simple application to show the intended functionality:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
# Header ------------------------------------------------
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Example Screening")
# Sidebar ------------------------------------------------
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
# Body ------------------------------------------------
body <-
dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
       column(6,h3("Screening Parameters")),
       column(6,h3("Filtered/Modified Results"))),
  fluidRow(
       column(6,DT::dataTableOutput("screening_params")),
       column(6,DT::dataTableOutput("filtered_results")))
)
# APP ------------------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui <- dashboardPage(
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
),
# Server ----------------------------------------------------------
shinyServer(function(input,output){

  output$screening_params <- renderDataTable({
    tibble(params = c("filter(mpg >= 21)",
                      "mutate(cyl_sq = cyl^2)",
                      rep_len(NA_character_,8))) %>%
      DT::datatable(rownames = F,
                    editable = T)
  })

  output$filtered_results <- renderDataTable({
    mtcars %>%
      # input$screening_params
      DT::datatable()

  })

}))
```

I would be open to using either the `DT` or `rhandsontable` or any alternative that someone can think of. Unfortunately it doesn't look like you can grab the edited table values in `DT`, but hopefully it provides a good example of what I am after.

I have tried every combination of quosures and mapping functions that I can think of to no avail.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly different approach, but maybe you'll find it useful. I'm using `sqldf` as an SQL query engine, and users can manipulate the data using ad-hoc SQL queries on the given dataset. If this isn't what you're after, I at least hope it will give you some hints on how to do it with `dplyr` syntax.

If you still go for the `dplyr` option and you have a string with the requested manipulation, you can use the reactive method `getDataset` to evaluate the expression you received from the user, manipulate your dataset. Then call `getDataset` in the `renderDataTable` method, like I did in the attached code.

Example for evaluating a string expression:

```
eval(parse(text="res <- mtcars %>% filter(mpg < 20)"))
```

For the SQL option:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)
# Header ------------------------------------------------
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Example Screening")
# Sidebar ------------------------------------------------
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE)
# Body ------------------------------------------------
body <-
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      #column(6,h3("Screening Parameters")),
      column(6,h3("Filtered/Modified Results"))),
    fluidRow(
      textInput("sql","SQL Query",value = "SELECT * FROM dataset"),
      DT::dataTableOutput(("filtered_results"))
    )
  )
# APP ------------------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui <- dashboardPage(
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
),
# Server ----------------------------------------------------------
shinyServer(function(input,output){

  ## A new function to load data and perform the SQL query on it
  getDataset <- reactive({
    query <- input$sql
    dataset <- mtcars
    sqldf::sqldf(query)
  })

  output$filtered_results <- renderDataTable({
    getDataset() %>%
      DT::datatable()

  })

}))
```

Comment: I appreciate the post! I'm aware of the `eval(parse(text=.))`  solution for using a character value to execute code, however, I have not been able to find a way where you could iterate this over multiple parameters. Do you have any ideas on how to make that work iterated over 10 or 15 character vectors? e.g. `c("filter(mpg >= 21)","mutate(cyl_sq = cyl^2)")`

Comment: You can try pasting the strings together with a %>% between them, and then `eval` the entire thing

Comment: I will mark this as the answer, it's funny because that totally makes sense, but I just never even thought of that haha. I will post the final app, will do a fair bit of cleaning it up, but really appreciate you sending back and forth ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Omri374 for bouncing ideas back and forth with me.

**Simple Application that satisfies the requirements:**

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(rhandsontable)
# Header ------------------------------------------------
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Example Screening")
# Sidebar ------------------------------------------------
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
# Body ------------------------------------------------
body <-
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(6,h3("Screening Parameters")),
      column(6,h3("Filtered/Modified Results"))),
    fluidRow(
      column(6, rHandsontableOutput("hot")),
      column(6, dataTableOutput("filtered_results")))
  )
# APP ------------------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui <- dashboardPage(
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
),
# Server ----------------------------------------------------------
shinyServer(function(input,output){

  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    tibble(params = c("filter(mpg >= 21)",
                      "filter(cyl == 4)",
                      "mutate(cyl_sq = cyl^2)",
                      "select(cyl,mpg,drat)",
                      rep_len(NA_character_,6))) %>%
      rhandsontable() %>%
      hot_cols(colWidths = 500)
  })

  output$filtered_results <- renderDataTable({


    df <- mtcars

    params <- input$hot %>%
      hot_to_r() %>%
      filter(!is.na(params),params != "") %>%
      mutate(params = ifelse(row_number() == max(row_number()),
                             params,
                             paste0(params," %>% "))) %>%
      pull(params) %>%
      str_c(collapse = "")


    if(length(params)>=1){

      eval(parse(text = paste0("filt_df <- df %>%",params)))

    } else {

      filt_df <- df

    }

    filt_df %>%
      datatable()



  })

}))
```